# IE6 Doesn't like my CSS :(

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Web site: srstage.d19.us (sorry would only allow one link)

How it looks in IE6: http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/4489/6c1bafd63a9d33b1231bd3d.png

The 4 bugs are marked.

1. no dotted border (on navigation and date badge) (from memory that isn't supported by IE6)
2. sidebar mostly gone
3. comment-meta is blank
4. date badge is moved (positioning bug?)

I hate IE6, however some organisations stupidly use it... :(

Comment: Is there a question or were you merely venting? If the latter, you have my sympathy.

Comment: Unsolicited commentary: that's a pretty nice looking site, but the background image is pretty contrasty for a background. On the other hand, I had an awful time translating the content ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking for help with the bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these solutions are a bit hacky, but they should solve all of the bugs:

```
/* Problem 1 */

div#menu ul
{
    line-height: 2;
}

/* Problem 2 */

div#content
{
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* Problem 3 */

.entry-meta
{
    zoom: 1;
}

/* Problem 4 */

.entry-title, .entry-content, .entry-meta
{
    margin-left: 55px;
}

div.post
{
    padding-left: 0;
}

.entry-shortdate
{
    margin: 0;
    top: 20px;
    left: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I just shoved it in:
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie6.css" />
    <![endif]-->

and all is well.
The only thing that doesn't work is the date badge's border. I remember seeing something about using an image for the border.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for you:

Don't use absolute positioning in the date boxes: Use negative margin and floats.

Your sidebar drops below the entries because there's no room for it. There are two mistakes with the boxing (at least): The #container takes all space on the page, and #primary is not inside the container. #primary is floated right but comes after the content on the left. With float=right the right-floated box should be placed before left-floated boxes.

Make your menu's ul as high as the anchors inside it.

Use position=relative for comment meta.

It would be a lot more easiear for you to use a CSS framework which has already solved these problems. For example [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).

Comment: How would I use negative margins and floats for the datebox?

Comment: {float:left;margin:0 0 0 -40px;} for example. It might work without floating the datebox too. I haven't tested with your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to fix the sidebar though. How should I fix my "boxing"?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [IE7.JS](http://IE7) to make IE6 behave like standard-compliant browsers.

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer behave
>   like a standards-compliant browser. It
>   fixes many HTML and CSS issues and
>   makes transparent PNG work correctly
>   under IE5 and IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Use a doctype declaration like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

for more information on aligning, go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp